# Map Service as Basemap object, ArcGIS Server to ArcGIS JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-server

I have a Map Service on my ArcGIS Server that contains the basemap layer. I have its REST URL like: *https://server/arcgis/rest/services/Basemap/Basemap1/FeatureServer*

How do I do something like:
*basemap: new Basemap(...);*
to put it into a Basemap object, latter be used inside a Map and a MapView/SceneView object?